# htaccess how to redirect subdirectory to external URL

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I tried:

```
//301 Redirect Old File
Redirect 301 www.mydomain.com/subdirectory http://newurl.com
```

but that lands me at newurl.com/subdirectory, which doesn't exist.

Comment: I've asked this before and scoured the web for an answer and come up with nothing. I'm assuming this cannot be done with htaccess. Guess PHP will have to do.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess then add this code in your .htaccess under DOCUMENT_ROOT:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^subdirectory/?$ http://newurl.com [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: This would go in the htaccess file inside the subdirectory, correct?

Comment: No in your main .htaccess under DOCUMENT_ROOT