# 301 redirect from subdomain with subfolder to different domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Like the title says, I need to redirect from a subdomain with a subfolder to a different domain. It's important the full url is written from the subdomain, because I have more subdomains that need redirection.

I've tried the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub-domain.com/en/folder/subfolder/1$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/folder/subfolder-12602124/ [R=301,L]
```

But this doesnt seem to work. 
I can't redirect from the root because multiple domains are on this root sadly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^subdirectory/?$ http://newurl.com [L,R=301,NC]
```

[htaccess how to redirect subdirectory to external URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10034152/htaccess-how-to-redirect-subdirectory-to-external-url)